# Icon to collapse regions and class members does not appears

Tags: visual-studio

When I open a .cs file from the project in Visual Studio, all code are expanded and the icon minus to collapse regions and class members not appear in the file editor.

Then I do the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to collapse all regions, thereafter all regions and class members are collapsed and the icon plus appear, after this the functionality to collapse and expand regions and class members work normally in this file.

I thought some extension was causing this problem, but after disabling all extensions the problem persists.

I noticed that this problem started to occur after I used a macro to collapse all regions and class members on file when is open, but this wasn't immediately. Even removing the macro the problem persists.

Another developer who works with me has same problem.
He also used the macro to collapse all regions when file is open.

I did a test with a Forms project and the problem also appears.

The macro that I use is from here:
http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/collapse-defintions-default-ie-103343.aspx

Comment: I recently formatted my machine and I am using Windows 8, again installed Visual Studio 2010 and some extensions that I use. And again the problem is occurring. Also installed Visual Studio 2012 and the problem also occurred.